# Error when running Jekyll command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jekyll, chmod

I accidentally ran the command sudo chmod 600 -R / when I meant to do it to sudo chmod 600 -R Documents/some_directory and my macbook pro's file permissions got messed up. I ran sudo chmod 755 -R /directories_that_don't_need_to_be_secure and tried to fix all the permissions. But when I start my Jekyll server jekyll --server --auto I hit a bunch of errors. I made my whole directory readable, writable, and executable. But the error keeps popping up. This is what I get when the jekyll server generates:

```
    Shalin-Shah-Me:shalin shalinvs$ jekyll --server --auto
Configuration from /Users/shalinvs/Documents/Developer/Websites/shalin/_config.yml
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- sass (LoadError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/shalinvs/Documents/Developer/Websites/shalin/_plugins/sass_converter.rb:5
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:78:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:77:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:77:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:76:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:76:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:31:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/jekyll:238:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.12.0/bin/jekyll:238
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:23
```

I have also tried using Disk Utility to repair my permissions but still no luck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you reinstall your gems?

Comment: No, I just reinstalled my jekyll and rails gem. None of the other ones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you get with this?

```
gem list sass
```

Try this:

```
gem uninstall sass
gem install sass
```

Then run your jekyll command again.

Comment: Thanks! I had to also install the s3cmd gem and the compass gem but s3cmd doesn't work properly. I'll accept your answer and make this a separate question. Thanks!